# Generic way to get reference to a method's caller?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 2 classes representing 2 objects. From the "whoCalledMe" function, I want to find out what object called the function (without passing that information in as an argument). I've used a make-believe property, "caller", that would give me the reference I'm looking for. Is there a generic way I can get a reference to the caller from there?

```
package {
    public class ObjectCallingTheFunction {
        public var IDENTITY:String = "I'm the calling function!";

        public function ObjectCallingTheFunction() {
            var objectWithFunction:ObjectWithFunction = new ObjectWithFunction();
            objectWithFunction.whoCalledMe();
        }
    }
}

package {
    public class ObjectWithFunction {
        public function whoCalledMe ():void {
            trace(caller.IDENTITY); // Outputs: "I'm the calling function!"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this question is scary...what was I doing? Reasons not to do this @ "cyclical/circular dependencies" or "directed acyclic graph".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to know why you need this, because I have a feeling that you don't really. If the method is anonymous, you can bind the 'this' keyword by using .apply on the method:

```
var foo:Function = function(arg:int):void
{
    trace(this);
};

var bar:Object = {
    toString: function():String { return "bar"; }
};

var baz:Object = {
    toString: function():String { return "baz"; }
};

foo.apply(bar); // <-- Prints "bar"
foo.apply(baz); // <-- Prints "baz"
```

If the method is an instance method method however, it's a bound method and thus "this" will always point to the instance of the class it's declared in, no matter if you redefine it by using the apply method. If it's a static method, "this" doesn't make sense and the compiler will catch it.

Other than that, there's really no way short of declaring it as a parameter. There used to be a caller property on the arguments object, but it was deprecated when AS3 was released. You can get a reference to the function itself through arguments.callee, but that's not really what you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

In AS3 you can throw an error and then parse the Stack Trace to find out detailed informations.

You can check here for an example:

http://www.actionscript-flash-guru.com/blog/18-parse-file-package-function-name-from-stack-trace-in-actionscript-as3

If you want to find the called function's name you can follow this example:

http://www.flashontherocks.com/2010/03/12/getting-function-name-in-actionscript-3/

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that works with release runtimes. Also, you won't get the instance of the caller although I'm not clear if that's what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to know the caller in debug purpose. if so I would recommend setting a breakpoint in the method/function instead of tracing. When the code breaks you can backtrace the caller and a lot more. Works in Flash IDE as well as Flashbuilder. Google "as3 breakpoints" if you are new to breakpoints.

Comment: I want to know for runtime purposes, not debug purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official Adobe article on using arguments.callee

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/arguments.html

It includes sample code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This won't tell me from where the function was told to execute.